# Need 301 redirect from shared server ip address to domain name

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

A client of mine site was built during the time there was no domain point to it. So the url was something like this

```
http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/~weburl/
```

The problem is google picked up on this url and since then it has not picked up on the new domain that was propagated.

I need a 301 redirect setup so it will pick up on the new domain. Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this in the `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the following `.htaccess` file and place in in the root folder of your old domain(from [[1]](http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php)):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In case the web server in your shared environment disallows you to create such an `.htaccess` file you can try doing the redirect instead with PHP. Given that PHP is available, place to following `index.php` file into your `public_html` folder:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.newdomain.com/");
exit();
?>
```

Comment: I think this is incorrect.  He only wants to route `/~weburl/`, not the whole domain.

Comment: Oh is it? He states using a shared server implying he only has access to modify `.htaccess` for `weburl` folder.

Comment: It seems to work. and yes weburl is the root folder. anything I type with that ip redirects to the proper domain. thanks. hopefully this will fix the google issue.

Comment: A simple [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) inside the `~weburl`'s `.htaccess` file does the job. Paths are extended automatically. You don't need *Mod Rewrite*  for that.